# Using where on a joined table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

I got a scenario where i got a table with Events(header, description) and a table with Tags(tag, event_id) that contains tags that are linked to each Event.

What I would like to do is to be able to search for a specific word in the Events-table and at the same time search for the word in the Tags-table and get the Events that was found.

I'm abled to search the events with the following SQL

```
"SELECT events.* FROM events WHERE (header = 'query')"
```

But when I try to include the tags with a join I get nothing in return

```
"SELECT events.* FROM events INNER JOIN tags ON tags.events_id =
events.id AND WHERE (events.header = 'query' OR tags.tag = 'query')"
```

Is there some other way in which I can perform the join or do I need to perform two queries, one for the events and one getting the events which got a matching tag?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is there an AND keyword before the WHERE keyword?

Comment: Could you add some sample data? This query should work if there is at least 1 tag added to the event and if either the header or tag is `'query'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `AND` before `WHERE`

```
SELECT events.* 
FROM events INNER JOIN tags ON tags.events_id = events.id -- NO AND
WHERE (events.header = 'query' OR tags.tag = 'query')
```

Comment: This worked better, however this seems to require the Event to have tags associated with it. I would like to retrieve every Event, based on its header or its tags.

Comment: @nbon In that case use LEFT JOIN instead

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  events.* 
FROM 
  events 
  LEFT JOIN 
    tags 
  ON 
    tags.events_id = events.id
WHERE 
  tags.tag = 'query' OR
  events.header = 'query'
```

or this:

```
SELECT 
  events.* 
FROM 
  events,
  tags 
WHERE
  events.id = tags.events_id AND
  events.header = 'query' AND
  tags.tag = 'query'
```

But if what you meant was to return the event if the query was found in `event.header` or `tags.tag`, then use the latter and replace `AND` with `OR`

**EDIT:**

I forgot to include the `events.id = tags.events_id` statement

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that this query doesn't return anything if the search-query isn't matched in any events. Let's say the search-query match a tag, this query does return the event as expected, but only as long as the header matches aswell.

I need something like OR WHERE events.header = 'query' i guess

Comment: Ah, the latter one seems to work better, but I'm getting some weird results with the tag-match, is there some way to specify how the tables should be joined and still keep the WHERE-clause as in the second example?

Comment: What weird results do you get?

Comment: The second example is not correct. You need to put the matching relation between two table like `tags.events_id = events.id`. Without this you will end up with the cross product between two tables. No doubt you are getting weird result :)

Comment: Seems like i managed to solve it based on your last example!

    `code"SELECT distinct(events.id) FROM events, tags WHERE 
    events.id = tags.events_id AND tags.tag = 'query' OR  
    events.header = 'query'"`

This returns the correct events based on their header or based on their matching tags. Thanks a lot for the help Roland and @Talha

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT  
  events.*  
FROM  
  events RIGHT OUTER JOIN  tags  ON events.id = tags.events_id
WHERE
  events.header = 'query' OR
  tags.tag = 'query'
```